# How to tune the number of goroutines used to download N files?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm making a Golang program which needs to download *N* files and then perform some task on each one. In particular there is a pipeline of operation to do on each single SWF file:

1. Make an http get request to get the file
2. Save it locally
3. Convert it in PNG

Doing it sequentially could be very inefficient. Doing it with *N* goroutines could also be non-optimal.

How do I choose / limit the number of goroutines?

Comment: 7. No, just kidding. It all depends. Your question is unanswerable. It mostly depends on your definition of "large": Is it 100, 100 thousand, 100 million or 100 billion? How fast can you suck the data, how fast process it? The proper approach is think about it, implement it, measure it and improve it. Repeat.

Comment: 42 seems like a nice number.

Comment: I have fixed the link (in the answer below) regarding the limit of opened files on Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36841/7490

Comment: I think I've trimmed the question down to an answerable core. Can we take off the hold?

Comment: The question is harder to answer not knowing what task you're performing on the files. Lightweight?, disk/cpu/network intensive? Long/short duration?

Comment: I know that's a very broad question. I've reported it in this way because I think that could be some golden rules to solve this kind of situation. I've improved my question inserting the specific task that I need to do on each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [goroutine](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines) is lightweight by design:

> A goroutine has a simple model: it is a function executing concurrently with other goroutines in the same address space. It is lightweight, costing little more than the allocation of stack space. And the stacks start small, so they are cheap, and grow by allocating (and freeing) heap storage as required.

The limit is not in the number of goroutines you generate, but in what they do.

In your case, opening files (to write a downloaded stream) concurrently could meet the [limit of number of opened files per process or in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36841/7490)